# How do I get a hash for a picture form a Steam Game?

Tags: image, icons, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I want to get a image/logo/icon from steam games with the steam web api, but the problem with the api is, they ask for a hash in the url. Where can I get the hash?

Steam api link:
 http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/{appid}/{hash}.jpg

Example:
http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/07385eb55b5ba974aebbe74d3c99626bda7920b8.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Most of their official API endpoints, such as GetOwnedGames (documented [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29) to get owned games for an user), return application details when setting the `include_appinfo` query parameter to `true`.

The returned details then include the hashes you were looking for, as `img_icon_url` and `img_logo_url` in a game's object.

As written in their docs,

> these are the filenames of various images for the game. To construct the URL to the image, use this format:
>
> [http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/{appid}/{hash}.jpg](http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/%7Bappid%7D/%7Bhash%7D.jpg)

Here's an example of a request `http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&steamid=YOUR_STEAM_ID&include_appinfo=true&format=json`

And a game's result key from this very request.

```
         {
            "appid": 400,
            "name": "Portal",
            ...
            "img_icon_url": "cfa928ab4119dd137e50d728e8fe703e4e970aff",
            "img_logo_url": "4184d4c0d915bd3a45210667f7b25361352acd8f",
            ...
        },
```

So, for the portal logo the resulting URL would be http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/400/4184d4c0d915bd3a45210667f7b25361352acd8f.jpg

Comment: `img_logo_url` does not returned

Comment: Hi. It does appear that the `img_logo_url` is no longer returned as of today. I have confirmed this behavior with a sample of ~300 games. However, there was no API version change and the documentation still indicates that it should be returned. I will leave the answer as is for now, until either the issue or the documentation is fixed.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use the store's appdetails API to get all the CDN images available. Replace APP_ID. https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=APP_ID .

Answer (score 2):

Replace `440` with any other valid ID of game/app. That's what you need.

> https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/440/header.jpg

Answer (score 1):

there is 4 kind of image to use with steam app id.

https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1569040/hero_capsule.jpg
https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1569040/capsule_616x353.jpg
https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1569040/header.jpg   https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1569040/capsule_231x87.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).