# Is there a faster way to get html element from another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm using jQuery to get HTML element from another website, but it takes too long to get data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < matchedGames.length; i++) {

            var gamePageUrl = `https://store.steampowered.com/app/${matchedGames[i]}`
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var a = document.createElement("a")

            var gameImage = document.createElement("img")
            var src = null
            var imageHTML = null

            a.setAttribute("href", gamePageUrl)

            await $.get(proxyUrl+gamePageUrl, function(imgData){
                imageHTML = $(imgData).find("div.game_header_image_ctn").html()
                if(imageHTML == undefined){
                    imageHTML = $(imgData).find("div.img_ctn").html()
                }
                
            })

            if (imageHTML == undefined) {
                continue
            }
            else {
                src = $(imageHTML).attr('src')

                gameImage.setAttribute('src', src)
                gameImage.setAttribute('width', 300)

                a.appendChild(gameImage)

                li.appendChild(a)
                li.setAttribute("id", `game_${i}`)

                ul.appendChild(li);
            }

        }
        alert("it's done")
```

I'm using $.get method to get img element, but like I said the process takes too long to get that element from the target website. User has to wait so long to see the result. For example, 10 image takes approximately 10-15 seconds to get.

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/dev? - you should get familiar of using an `API`. Steam provides a lot of stuff in their APIs i guess

Comment: or is it really about some HTML elements you want to get?

Comment: I'm already using Steam API to get user data, but I couldn't find any game information data in Steam API. I'm trying to get game images and I didn't find game information JSON file in API. So, I tried to get the image from the specific game URL.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963328/how-do-i-get-a-hash-for-a-picture-form-a-steam-game

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I overlooked the arguments. My bad.